# Hack the behaviour of window.location.replace, use a javascript instead of URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible in some way to hack the behaviour of `window.location.replace`, to fire a JavaScript function (let's say `alert`) instead of making the user go to the new location?

I'll give you the example, let's say we have this function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("#SOMETHING_HERE#"); }, 900);
```

this is fired when a user clicks on a specific button; the `#SOMETHING_HERE#` is a placeholder, the administrator can put there a URL via a configuration panel.

Now, we all know clients are weird, and mine has just asked me to find a way to fire a JavaScript instead of redirect the user, well, I'm stuck. Of course I should modify the function bound to the button, but actually I have no access to the code and the only entry point is that panel I've mentioned before, I can only change the value of `#SOMETHING_HERE#`.
Do someone has some clues on how I could for example fire an alert("foo"); ? is that possible in some way?

the answer could be also "NO" and I'll simply say them that we have to find a way to change that code.

Comment: If its validation is crappy, try `"); alert("whatever`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet

Comment: Client is not being weird here since I don't think client would have asked you to use ocation.replace at first place. Why can't you invoke location.replace conditionaly?

Comment: the code isn't mine and I don't know the workflow and decisions taken when it was first written :(

Comment: `the code isn't mine` You can still change the code to fire it conditionally `location.replace`

Comment: LOL the only real solution is to inject javascript through a "we-are-lucky-this-allows-xss!" control panel (the first comment here on top)... WOW. Tell client that this is what happens when you don't have a budget for a web application. Hacks will get you nowhere and this is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: thanks to all that give usefull informations ;) 
actually, I've had a bad discussion with them exactly for that reason Sharky, they don't want to spend money, and they want things done... and at the end the thing is always "we should go to someone else, if you are not able to do that" :(

Comment: and just FYI, this are the last changes I'll do on their system, and then I'll be free of those ppl, I just reply something like, "ok, find someone else" ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prefix your string with `javascript:`:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace("javascript:alert('hello world!')"); }, 900);
```

This works because the spec for `location.replace` ends up at the [definition for "navigate"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigate), which says:

> 14. This is the step that attempts to obtain the resource, if necessary. Jump to the first appropriate substep:
>
> ...
>
> If the new resource is a URL whose scheme is javascript
>
> Queue a task to run these "javascript: URL" steps, associated with the active document of the browsing context being navigated:

Comment: this is perfect, really really thanks, also for the informations!